# How to detect if the user is on a new page if the URI does not change, e.g. on a Single Page Application?

Tags: javascript

I need to be able to detect when the user has visited a new page within the same website. For example, he goes to the index page, and then navigates to the contact page.

I need to do this detection using JS.

Everything is fine if each page has a separate URI, but I'm finding a lot of websites, especially SPAs, don't change the URI when the user navigates about. So everything is `/`.

My question is this: is there another way to detect when the user has navigated to a different page? For example, is there some window or document value which would tell me it's a unique page?

Comment: can you post some of the url's you are monitoring?  angular / spa pages contain the # as a page separator; others might do some other trickery to hide the url

Comment: I'm sorry, I cannot share the pages (NDA). The URI is currently being taken from `window.location.pathname` and it always shows `/`. This accurately reflects what the browser is displaying too.

Comment: do the URL's have the # in the querystring?

Comment: No they don't... ;(

Comment: can you use something like the new Resource Timing API's?   https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Resource_Timing_API/Using_the_Resource_Timing_API

Comment: Hmm! I don't know. Let me explore. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Depending on browser compatibility requirements you may use [the history API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API) to emulate and track page navigation without doing a full page load.

### History API Example

From Mozilla MDN:

```
history.replaceState(stateObj, "page 3", "bar2.html");
```

> This will cause the URL bar to display http://mozilla.org/bar2.html,
>   but won't cause the browser to load bar2.html or even check that
>   bar2.html exists.

By emulating navigation using `replaceState` and its sibling function `pushState` you can detect the navigation using the `window.onpopstate` event.

Example of window.onpopstate, again, [from MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onpopstate):

```
window.onpopstate = function(event) {
  alert("location: " + document.location + ", state: " + JSON.stringify(event.state));
};

history.pushState({page: 1}, "title 1", "?page=1");
history.pushState({page: 2}, "title 2", "?page=2");
history.replaceState({page: 3}, "title 3", "?page=3");
history.back(); // alerts "location: http://example.com/example.html?page=1, state: {"page":1}"
history.back(); // alerts "location: http://example.com/example.html, state: null
history.go(2);  // alerts "location: http://example.com/example.html?page=3, state: {"page":3}
```

### Legacy alternative: using location.hash (#)

For legacy browsers some SPAs, e.g. Google Maps, achieve(d) similar behaviour using `window.location.hash` and the `window.onhashchange` event.  Often these took the form of 'hashbang' fragment identifiers, e.g. `#!/some/page.html`, a format made popular a [Google proposal](https://webmasters.googleblog.com/2009/10/proposal-for-making-ajax-crawlable.html) but for which [quite compelling reasons](http://isolani.co.uk/blog/javascript/BreakingTheWebWithHashBangs) exist for not using it as a routing mechanism.  This is especially true now that we have improvements to History API.